# Require at least one MultiFieldPanel object [wagtail]

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a `content_panels` definition that includes this:

```
MultiFieldPanel(
    [
        InlinePanel('related_resource_type', label="Resource Type",),
    ],
    heading="Resource Type",
    classname="collapsible"
),
```

This references

```
class RelatedResourceType(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey('ShopPage', related_name='related_resource_type')
    resource_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=16,
        choices=shopchoices.RESOURCE_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default="shop"
    )
```

Is there a way in Wagtail to require at least one `RelatedResourceType`? Preferably I would also have the ability to specify a minimum number of `RelatedResourceTypes`. I cannot find in the documentation how to specify required panels. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InlinePanel takes an optional `min_num` argument.

> Finally, min_num and max_num allow you to set the minimum/maximum number of forms that the user must submit

From http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10.1/reference/pages/panels.html?highlight=min#inline-panels-and-model-clusters